# Reshaping tables, with old values as the new table's columnnames

Tags: mysql

I'm looking for a query that allows me to "flatten" rows with the same ID:

- Values from the second column are used as the new tables column names
- Values from the third column determine the values in the new table.

As an example:

A table looks like this.

```
ID       year     event
------------------------
Guid1    2005     A
Guid1    2010     B
Guid2    2020     C
```

I want it to look like..

```
ID       2005      2010     2020
Guid1    A         B        
Guid2                       C
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume (id, year) combination is unique? Otherwise not sure what output you expect. If unique, it looks like this:

```
SELECT
  id,
  MIN(IF(year = 2005, event, NULL)) AS '2005',
  MIN(IF(year = 2010, event, NULL)) AS '2010',
  MIN(IF(year = 2020, event, NULL)) AS '2020'
FROM
  t
GROUP BY
  id
```

The above means you'll have to repeat the `MIN(IF(...))` statement once for each desired year. There is no way in SQL to do this automatically: SQL does not mix data and metadata. You cannot dynamically specify columns in a query. Either you use "*" or you specify the exact columns.

Comment: That´s it. I didn´t know you could use MIN like that to trick GROUP BY. Thanks!

Comment: Just noting I have edited the code and have added quotes around column names as they are numeric.